# Paypal Rest Api returns 401 Unauthorized when i try to get OAuth2 token using php file_get_contents() in localhost with sandbox , but works in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, rest, paypal

Paypal Rest Api returns 401 Unauthorized when i try to get OAuth2 token using php file_get_contents() in localhost with sandbox

```
    $client_id = env('PAYBAL_CLIENT');
    $client_secret = env('PAYPAL_SECRET');

    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            "headers" => [
                "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Authorization" => "Basic " . base64_encode("$client_id:$client_secret")
            ],
            'body' => "{'grant_type' : 'client_credentials'}"
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    $url = "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";

    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

the same requeste worked fine with me in ajax

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
    type:"post",
    headers:{
        "Authorization": "Basic 'XXXbase64_encodedXXX'"
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    data:{
        "grant_type":"client_credentials"
    },
    success:function (data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    complete:function (data,status){
        console.log(status);
    }
}
```

);

Comment: is it a spelling mistake `$client_id = env('PAYBAL_CLIENT');` PAYBAL

Comment: @cmgchess No , I Checked it , that's how i recorded the variable

Answer (score 1):

The ajax function is converting the data to url encoded format for you here:

```
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    data:{
        "grant_type":"client_credentials"
    },
```

PHP's curl does not do that (or especially when you give it a string instead of an array/object, there's no way it can guess that it needs to be converted; it will assume any string you pass is the string you intend to post)

```
'body' => "{'grant_type' : 'client_credentials'}"
```

You must supply a form url-encoded body string as the API call requires: `"grant_type=client_credentials"`

Comment: I will be gratfull if you ellaborate more , I tried by making my code like this $opts = ['http' => [
            'method' => 'POST',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization' => "Basic " . base64_encode("$client_id:$client_secret"),
            'body' => ['grant_type' => urlencode('client_credentials')]
            ]
        ];   it still gave 401 unAuthorized

Comment: Have you read the API reference that explains how to request an access token? The required string is `"grant_type=client_credentials"`

Comment: yes i read it , I have tried 'body' =>  urlencode('grant_type=client_credentials') , Along With So many Other Attemps , it still giving me 401 unAuthorized If You Tried it before and worked with you , please show me an example .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of file_get_contents I uses GuzzleHttp And It Worked With Me , Here is the code

```
        $client_id = env('PAYBAL_CLIENT');
    $client_secret = env('PAYPAL_SECRET');
    
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token', [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization' => "Basic " . base64_encode("$client_id:$client_secret")
        ],
        'body' => 'grant_type=client_credentials'
    ]);
```